# SQL WHERE IN ... to JOIN table

Tags: sql, sqlite, self-join, join, where-in

```
SELECT
    sum(CheckFinal.SUM) AS SUME,
    strftime('%Y - %m', CheckDate) AS CheckDate
FROM 
    CheckFinal
WHERE CheckFinal.NUMER IN (
    SELECT 
        CheckDetail.NUMER
    FROM
        CheckDetail
    WHERE
        CheckDetail.NUMER IN (
            SELECT 
                PriceList.UniqID AS PriceListUniqID, 
                PriceList.Name AS PriceListName,
                Category.UniqID
            FROM
                PriceList Join Category on PriceList.CATEGORY = Category.UniqID
            WHERE (Category.UniqID = 2)
        )
)
GROUP BY strftime('%Y %m', CheckDate);
```

I have such query to combine data out of 4 tables:
— Category (100 records)
— PriceList (20'000 records)
— CheckDetail (10'000'000 records)
— CheckFinal (2'000'000 records)

In plain word, I'm looking for PriceList items, that are marked as children of Category.UniqID #2, then I would like to collect all CheckDetail.NUMER inset to define all sales value with such PriceList items. Futhermore, I'm looking for possobility to collect all CheckFinal.NUMERs.

The problem I have is:

1. It's not possible to make SELECT procedure three (3) time nested (SQLite.3), I think it's time to make JOINs but I have no experience in joining
2. CheckDetail is a HUGE data set, it's take 2 seconds to find just one PriceList item across 10 million records and I have 3'000 items in my query `WHERE (Category.UniqID = 2)`

In my case, I should lookup 3'000 times through 5'000'000 records, but I have 10 sets and the query will spend about 10 hours to complit.

Is JOIN will optimize query time? How to make such JOIN QUERY?

Is there any GUI tools to make query with constructor or something like that?

**UPD**:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/50a93/2 (use SQL.js for inserting several rows of data)

Comment: If you provide an sqlFiddle i may give it a try.

Comment: I would suggest that you should not be querying any database ever under any circumstances with a thorough understanding of joins. And under no circumstances shoud you use a GUI to do the joining, you need to understand this stuff, it is basic.

Comment: Performance optimization is not possible if you keep the database schema a secret.

Comment: The schema is not a secret but tricky. It have another fields and table names and it's dbf originally converted to SQLite for my own purpose. I'll try to make sqlFiddle and put it in the question.

Comment: Updated with sqlFiddle link.

Comment: 1) total lack of primary keys 2) total lack of foreign keys 3) lack of additional indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WITH `JOIN` , you query would look like

```
       SELECT 
           sum(CF.SUM) AS SUME,
           strftime('%Y - %m', CF.CheckDate) AS CheckDate
       FROM
            PriceList 
            Join Category 
            on PriceList.CATEGORY = Category.UniqID
            AND Category.UniqID = 2
            JOIN CheckDetail CD
            ON CD.NUMBER = PriceList.UniqID
            JOIN CheckFinal CF
            ON CF.NUMBER = CD.NUMBER
        GROUP BY strftime('%Y - %m', CF.CheckDate);
```

Comment: I think you actually meant to do `group by strftime('%Y - %m', CF.CheckDate)`

Comment: @Daniel, with sirf value of 4 there are no records in archeck, for categ with value 2 only record with sirf 4 maching in main, also updated group by to be same as select. When sirf is given as 1, you get the result as there are matching records